# React Links out of context can't navigate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Setting up `react-router` and I'm getting an error `Uncaught Error: <Link>s rendered outside of a router context cannot navigate.`. I've read up everything I could find on github and here but I didn't find a solution that worked.

Here are the files in question.

Main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, BrowserHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Home from './components/Home/Home';
import About from './components/About/About';
import Apply from './components/Apply/Apply';
import Raiding from './components/Raiding/Raiding';
import Resources from './components/Resources/Resources';
import Register from './components/Register/Register';
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer';

const Main = () => {
    return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <BrowserRouter history={BrowserHistory}>
                    <main>
                        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                        <Route path='/about' component={About} />
                        <Route path='/apply' component={Apply} />
                        <Route path='/raiding' component={Raiding} />
                        <Route path='/resources' component={Resources} />
                        <Route path='/register' component={Register} />
                    </main>
                </BrowserRouter>
                <Footer />
            </div>
    )
}

export default Main;
```

Header.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Link } from 'react-router';

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <header id="site-header">
            <div className="container">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt=""/>

                <nav id="site-nav">
                    <Link className="site-nav-link" to="/about">About</Link>
                    <Link className="site-nav-link" to="/apply">Apply</Link>
                    <Link className="site-nav-link" to="/raiding">Raiding</Link>
                    <Link className="site-nav-link" to="/resources">Resources</Link>
                    <Link className="site-nav-link" to="/register">Register</Link>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Main from './app/Main';

import 'normalize.css';
import './index.scss';

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

What I am assuming is that the issue lies in the fact that my Header component (which contains Links) is out of context of the Main component (which contains the routing) but I haven't figured out a solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Link>` components depend on the `context.router` being present. `context.router` is set by the `<BrowserRouter>`. You should be rendering your `<Header>` component inside of the `<BrowserRouter>` and it will work as expected.

```js
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Header />
    <main>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
      <Route path='/about' component={About} />
      <Route path='/apply' component={Apply} />
      <Route path='/raiding' component={Raiding} />
      <Route path='/resources' component={Resources} />
      <Route path='/register' component={Register} />
    </main>
    <Footer />
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Side note, but `BrowserHistory` is not a thing in v4. The `<BrowserRouter>` is creating a `history` instance for you.

Comment: When I do change my main.js to look like that I get these bad boys :/ http://prntscr.com/e7wp1w

Comment: @KrešimirČoko You seem to be mixing code from React Router v2/3 (I'm not sure which one you have installed) with code from v4. Uninstall the old React Router, and change `import { Link } from 'react-router'` to `import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'`.